# jqGrid parameters. Can't be passed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I call web-service to fill jqGrid and wants to pass parameters to it

I use the following code (client side):

```
jQuery('#EmployeeTable').jqGrid({
    datatype: function () {
        var params = new Object();
        params.page = 10;
        params.Filter = true;
        params.DateStart = null;
        params.DateEnd = null;
        params.TagID = null;
        params.CategoryID = 3;
        params.StatusID = 1;
        params.IsDescription = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/IdeasJSON',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, st) {
                if (st == "success") {
                    var grid = $("#EmployeeTable")[0];
                    grid.addJSONData(data);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error with AJAX callback");
            }
        });
    },
```

also, there is propotype of web-method (MVC):

```
public JsonResult IdeasJSON(int? page, bool? Filter, DateTime? DateStart, DateTime? DateEnd, int? TagID, int? CategoryID, int? StatusID, bool? IsDescription)
```

Why all these parameters are null?

[ADDED 04/11]

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var StatusID = null, Filter = null, page = null, DateStart = null, DateEnd = null, TagID = null, CategoryID = null, IsDescription = null;
        if (jQuery.url.param('StatusID') != null) {
            StatusID = jQuery.url.param('StatusID');
        }

        if (jQuery.url.param('Filter') != null) {
            Filter = jQuery.url.param('Filter');
        }

        if (jQuery.url.param('page') != null) {
            page = jQuery.url.param('page');
        }

        if (jQuery.url.param('DateStart') != null) {
            DateStart = jQuery.url.param('DateStart');
        }

        if (jQuery.url.param('DateEnd') != null) {
            DateEnd = jQuery.url.param('DateEnd');
        }

        if (jQuery.url.param('TagID') != null) {
            TagID = jQuery.url.param('TagID');
        }

        if (jQuery.url.param('CategoryID') != null) {
            CategoryID = jQuery.url.param('CategoryID');
        }

        if (jQuery.url.param('IsDescription') != null) {
            IsDescription = jQuery.url.param('IsDescription');
        }



        jQuery('#EmployeeTable').jqGrid({
            url: '/Admin/IdeasJSON',
            datatype: 'json',
            postData: { page: page, Filter: Filter, DateStart: DateStart, DateEnd: DateEnd, TagID: TagID, StatusID: StatusID, CategoryID: CategoryID, IsDescription: IsDescription },
            jsonReader: {
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                root: "rows",
                repeatitems: false,
                id: ""
            },
            colNames: ['Logged By', 'Logging Agency (ID)', 'Title', 'Status', 'Points', 'Categories', 'Created Date', 'Description', 'Jira ID#', 'Portal Name', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'LoggedBy', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'LoggingAgencyID', width: 85 },
                        { name: 'Title', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'Status', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'Points', width: 40, align: 'center' },
                        { name: 'Categories', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'CreatedDate', width: 80, formatter: ndateFormatter },
                        { name: 'Description', width: 300 },
                        { name: 'JiraID', width: 55 },
                        { name: 'PortalName', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'IdeaID', width: 25, formatter: ActionDescriptionFormatter },
                        { name: 'IdeaID', width: 25, formatter: ActionEditFormatter },
                        { name: 'IdeaID', width: 25, formatter: ActionDeleteFormatter },
                        { name: 'IdeaGridCommentsAndSubideas', width: 25, formatter: ActionIdeaGridCommentsAndSubideas },
                        { name: 'IdeaGridCountVotes', width: 25, formatter: ActionIdeaGridCountVotes },
                        { name: 'IdeaGridCountVotes', width: 25, formatter: ActionIdeaGridLinkIdeas },
                        { name: 'IdeaGridCountVotes', width: 25, formatter: ActionIdeaGridIdeaType },
                    ],
            pager: '#EmployeeTablePager',
            width: 1000,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Idea List',
            excel: true
        }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#EmployeeTablePager', {
            add: false,
            edit: false,
            del: false,
            search: false,
            refresh: false
        }).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#EmployeeTablePager', {
            caption: " Export to Excel ",
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-bookmark",
            onClickButton: ReturnExcel,
            position: "last"
        }).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#EmployeeTablePager', {
            caption: " Export to CSV ",
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-bookmark",
            onClickButton: ReturnCSV,
            position: "last"
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `datatype` as the function to use the JSON data. Probably you used template of **very old** examples.

For example in the "UPDATED" part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) you could find full [demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemo.zip) which demonstrate how to use jqGrid in ASP.MVC 2.0 inclusive paging, sorting and filtering/advanced searching.

If you want post some additional parameters to the server as a part of jqGrid request you should use `postData` parameters in the form `postData: {CategoryID: 3, StatusID: 1, IsDescription:true, Filter: true}`

Comment: I really don't understand how it works. I see only that parameter named "sord" as parameter of method in controller and "sortorder" in javascript. How is it linked?

Comment: It is the same. jqGrid define the names of some parameters included in the url with respect of `prmNames` parameter (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)). Do you good understand how `datatype` as function or `addJSONData` work? You should not use the way.

Comment: yes, I understand now, it's very simple. I spent 3 hours and in result it was added 1 string :)

Comment: only one question - how to pass "page" value?

Comment: @user285336: the `page` value will be send automatically by jqGrid.

Comment: I need to specify which page should be opened after loading a grid

Comment: @user285336: It is just the `page` parameter (1-based) of jqGrid. Default value of the parameter is 1.

Comment: postData: { page: page, Filter: Filter, DateStart: DateStart, DateEnd: DateEnd, TagID: TagID, StatusID: StatusID, CategoryID: CategoryID, IsDescription: IsDescription }, does not work

Comment: @user285336: What you posted is not a code. To be able to help you you should post **full JavaScript code**. Now you spend only our time.

Comment: I can't add this to comment. Added full javascript to main post. When url has parameter named StatusID - it's passed, but "page" is not

Comment: @user285336: The first problem in your code: `page` parameter name what you get from the url is not the same what use jqGrid. You have name conflict and should use variable with another name. The second problem: you include many columns with **the same** `name` attributes (`'IdeaID'` `'IdeaGridCountVotes'`) which is not permitted. You have to assign unique names to columns.